# How to mark entites as cacheable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa

I have java jar library with JPA entities, spring repositories and spring services and now i included this library in project where i want some entities to be cacheable (cached in second level cache) and don't want to change library.

Is is possible to configure *Cachemanager* to include entities which are not market as `@Cacheable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the `persistence.xml`, you can add

```
<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
```

for a persistence unit to cache alle entities or

```
<shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

to enable caching for all entities but the ones you marked as `@Cacheable(false)` (see also https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SharedCacheMode.html)

Comment: This partially answers my question, but how to define which entities classes goes to cache and which don't

Comment: AFAIK you cannot selectively enable or disable entities for caching other than through an annotation - either enable all and disable selected ones with `@Cacheable(false)` or disable all and enable selected ones with `@Cacheable(true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hibernate's session-independent second level cache which can be used by multiple Hibernate `Session` you must first activate it.

First modify `persistence.xml`, so add:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

and property:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```

You can choose between `ALL` to cache all entities, `NONE` to don't cache any entities, `ENABLE SELECTIVE` to select the entities that will be cached and `DISABLE SELECTIVE` to select the entities that will not be cached. Prefer `ENABLE SELECTIVE` because it requires you to explicitly decide which entities are cached.

Annotate your entity with JPA `@Cacheable` or Hibernate `@Cache` annotation.

You can also use the `@Cacheable (false)` annotation to exclude an entity from caching if you use shared cache mode `DISABLE SELECTIVE`.

```
Hibernate doesn't use the second-level cache with JPQL or criteria queries.
```

If you want to use query caching modify `persistence.xml`, so add properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```

and activate caching for query with `setCacheable(boolean b);` method, (eg.) :

```
Session s = (Session) em.getDelegate(); 
Query q = s.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE id = :id"); 
q.setParameter("id", 1L); 
q.setCacheable(true); 
Book b = q.uniqueResult();
```

Hibernate now stores the result of this query in the query cache. When your next use case executes this query, Hibernate checks if the query cache contains a result for the given parameter values. If the cache contains a matching record, Hibernate gets the query result from there. Otherwise, it executes the query and store its result in the cache.